# Multiple attacks with a dancing weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

In DnD 3.5, the dancing weapon enchantment says it 'fights for four rounds using the base attack bonus of the one who loosed it'. Does that mean if my base attack bonus is +6/+1, the weapon will also get two attacks from my high BAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

Iterative attacks are part of the Base Attack Bonus rules and description; as such, anything that uses your BAB uses your iterative attacks unless it specifies otherwise, or is using a natural weapon (which have their own built-in exception). Since Dancing weapons do neither, they get the full benefit of your iteratives.

Comment: Does the dancing weapon get a full allotment of actions?  Is it capable of taking the full attack action required to utilize the extra attacks a higher BAB would give?  I don't see where it says either way.

Comment: Difficult to say since the wording is so poor (thanks, WotC) but I'd interpret "fights" as having the full complement of actions, especially since it's capable of independent movement.

Comment: Actually, movement is what made me question the actions the dancing sword gets.  According to the SRD, it always occupies the space of the person who activated it, and moves with them: "While dancing, it takes up the same space as the activating character and can attack adjacent foes (weapons with reach can attack opponents up to 10 feet away). The dancing weapon accompanies the person who activated it everywhere, whether she moves by physical or magical means."

Comment: Interesting. Well, the only thing I can say is that since "fights" is not a defined game term, you'd need to ask your DM - the absolute RAW is unclear. I'd probably rule that it can make the full compliment of attacks, but at that juncture my interpretation is just that - an interpretation.

Answer (score -6):

Well, I think they don't, because it uses your Base Attack Bonus (not Bonuses)
The +6/+1 are two (different) attack bonuses, so you have 2 attacks instead of just 1.

By the way, check the [glossary](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101210647/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_baseattackbonus&alpha=):

+6/+1 indicates you have a max of 2 attacks in a full round action, so if you have moved more than 5 feet you can just do a single attack with you first BAB (+6).

So, the "dancing weapon" has no level, no class, just the BAB of the one who lost it.

Any link for iterative attack rules?